# Query data in mongodb

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I'm starting to learn NodeJS and MongoDB. I would like to retrieve data from MongoDB but had problems:

Data:

```
{
"_id": ObjectId("58f6e6e09f800932f0285ea7"),
"id_user": "1",
"username": "admin",
"password": "123",
"area": {
    "livingroom": {
        "id_room" : "001",
        "devices" : [ 
            {
                "id_device" : "1",
                "device_name" : "Light 1",
                "status" : "0",
                "read-only" : "0"
            }, 
            {
                "id_device" : "2",
                "device_name" : "Light 2",
                "status" : "0",
                "read-only" : "1"
            }
        ]
    },

    "garage": {
        "id_room" : "002",
        "devices" : [ 
            {
                "id_device" : "1",
                "device_name" : "Light 1",
                "status" : "0",
                "read-only" : "0"
            }, 
            {
                "id_device" : "2",
                "device_name" : "Light 2",
                "status" : "0",
                "read-only" : "0"
            }
        ]
    },
}
```

}

Now, I just want only retrieve data in "livingroom" by using Nodejs:

```
app.get('/devices', function (req, res) {
mongodb.connect(url, function (err, db) {
    if (err) {
        console.log('Unable to connect to the mongoDB server. Error:', err);
    } else {
        console.log('Connection established to', url);
        var collection = db.collection('Home');
        collection.find({'area': 'livingroom'}).toArray(

            function (err, result) {
                if (err) {
                    console.log(err);
                } else if (result.length) {
                    res.send(result);

                } else {
                    console.log('No document(s) found with defined "find" criteria!');
                }
                db.close();
            }
        );
    }
});
```

});

But it didn't work as expected, I cannot receive anything. How can I resolve it ?

Comment: What do you mean by "It didn't work as expected"? Is it outputting something?. Or do you receive any errors?.

Comment: Depends on how your data looks, but maybe `collection.find({'area.living_room': {$ne: null}})`

Comment: I did not receive anything guys. Sorry about that.

Comment: Did you able to see "Connection established to" message

Comment: Also from your collection.find query i can see that you are finding **livingroom** (string) in area which does not exists in your collection. also **livingroom** is object not string

Comment: Yes,i see Connection established to... but when I use collection.find({'area.living_room': {$ne: null}}) then I receive entire data. How can I fix it

Comment: if you want the `living_room` subdocument you can do `collection.find({'area.living_room': {$ne: null}}, {'area.living_room':1}) `. That way you'll get the doc `{area:{living_room:{...}}}`

Comment: Pls find the answer below

Comment: @Jenian. It work ! Thank you. This query are new to me, coud you share some documents that relate to it.

Comment: @ryan I created an answer with a link to docs

Comment: @Jenian thank for your helping

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want the living_room subdocument only - you can do `collection.find({'area.living_room': {$ne: null}}, {'area.living_room':1})`.

That way you'll get the doc `{area:{living_room:{...}}`.

[read more](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/project-fields-from-query-results/#return-specific-fields-in-embedded-documents) about projecting embedded documents.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to retrieve `livingroom` with `id_room:"001"` you need to modify find query like this:

```
       var collection = db.collection('Home');
        collection.find({'area.livingroom.id_room':"001"},function(err,data){
           if(err){
             console.log(err); 
           }else{
             console.log(data);
           }
         db.close();
    })
```

If you want to retrieve by devices in `livingroom` with `id_device:"1"` ,you need to modify find query like this:

```
 collection.find({'area.livingroom.devices.id_device':"1"},function(err,data){....});
```